# import csv to OrderedDict and predict using regression

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression, predict

i build a regression model to predict energy ( 1 columns ) from 5 variables ( 5 columns ) ... i used my exprimental data to train and fit the model and it works with good score ...

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv('new.csv')
X = data.drop(['E'],1)
y = data['E']

from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, test_size=0.5 , 
random_state=2)

from sklearn import ensemble

clf1 = ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(n_estimators = 400, max_depth =5,
                                           min_samples_split = 2, loss='ls', 
                                           learning_rate = 0.1)
clf1.fit(X_train, y_train)
clf1.score(X_test, y_test)
```

but now i want to add a new csv file contain new data for mentioned 5 variables to OrderedDict and use the model to predict energy ...

with code bellow i manually insert row by row and it predict energy correctly

```
from collections import OrderedDict
new_data = OrderedDict([('H',48.52512), ('A',169.8379), ('P',55.52512),
                        ('R',3.058758), ('Q',2038.055)])
new_data = pd.Series(new_data)
data = new_data.values.reshape(1, -1)
clf1.predict(data)
```

but i cant do this with huge datasets and need to import csv file ... i do the bellow but cant figure it out ....

```
data_2 = pd.read_csv('new2.csv')
X_new = OrderedDict(data_2)
new_data = pd.Series(X_new)
data = new_data.values.reshape(1, -1)
clf1.predict(data)
```

but gives me : ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.

can anyone help me ??

Comment: When you do `pd.read_csv`, the `data_2` is a dataframe. Try passing that directly to `clf1.predict(data)`. Make sure to remove the `'E' column` is `new2.csv` contains that.